# Concatenating multilevel objects for filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This looks way bigger than it actually is, it's just the objects that making the question look large. But I think you'll need to see the shape of the whole thing

I have a bit of an issue with the shape of my object. When I click on check boxes it filters the object to return unique entries based on the id of the item. The object being filtered is an assignment of two arrays year and sector

```
const filterObject = {...years, ...sectors};
```

which looks like this:

```
filterObject =
{
  "2016": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "charity1",
      "sector": "Conservation",
      "year": 2016,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.3397,
      "longitude": 12.3731,
      "donations": 50000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/nature",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "charity4",
      "sector": "Sport",
      "year": 2016,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 50.5764627,
      "longitude": 9.2230577,
      "donations": 74000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/sport",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    }
  ],
  "2017": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "charity2",
      "sector": "Children",
      "year": 2017,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.0504,
      "longitude": 13.7373,
      "donations": 100000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/abstract",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    }
  ],
  "2018": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "charity3",
      "sector": "Seniors",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.5413,
      "longitude": 9.9158,
      "donations": 70000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/people",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "charity5",
      "sector": "Homeless",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.9500019,
      "longitude": 7.4836722,
      "donations": 60000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "charity6",
      "sector": "Homeless",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 50.9500019,
      "longitude": 6.4836722,
      "donations": 60000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    }
  ],
  "Conservation": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "charity1",
      "sector": "Conservation",
      "year": 2016,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.3397,
      "longitude": 12.3731,
      "donations": 50000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/nature",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    }
  ],
  "Children": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "charity2",
      "sector": "Children",
      "year": 2017,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.0504,
      "longitude": 13.7373,
      "donations": 100000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/abstract",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    }
  ],
  "Seniors": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "charity3",
      "sector": "Seniors",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.5413,
      "longitude": 9.9158,
      "donations": 70000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/people",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    }
  ],
  "Sport": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "charity4",
      "sector": "Sport",
      "year": 2016,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 50.5764627,
      "longitude": 9.2230577,
      "donations": 74000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/sport",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    }
  ],
  "Homeless": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "charity5",
      "sector": "Homeless",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.9500019,
      "longitude": 7.4836722,
      "donations": 60000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "charity6",
      "sector": "Homeless",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 50.9500019,
      "longitude": 6.4836722,
      "donations": 60000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    }
  ]
}
```

I think my filters are correct,

```
const markerObject = filterObject[self.id];
const markerID = markerObject["id"];
mapMarkers.filter(marker => marker[0].id !== markerID);
```

but when the check box is checked I get this:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "charity5",
      "sector": "Homeless",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.9500019,
      "longitude": 7.4836722,
      "donations": 60000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "charity6",
      "sector": "Homeless",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 50.9500019,
      "longitude": 6.4836722,
      "donations": 60000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "charity3",
      "sector": "Seniors",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.5413,
      "longitude": 9.9158,
      "donations": 70000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/people",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "charity5",
      "sector": "Homeless",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 51.9500019,
      "longitude": 7.4836722,
      "donations": 60000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "charity6",
      "sector": "Homeless",
      "year": 2018,
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "address": "",
      "Postleitzahl": "",
      "bundesland": "",
      "latitude": 50.9500019,
      "longitude": 6.4836722,
      "donations": 60000,
      "image": "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city",
      "logo": "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract"
    }
  ]
]
```

As you can see there are duplicate entries, I think it's caused by the shape of the origional object 'filterObject'.

Here's the whole code https://codepen.io/sharperwebdev/pen/rdeeeY?editors=0011 lines 266 to 302

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does years contain the same data as sectors?

Comment: Sort of. There is a large object from an API which is split into two objects. Each new object is grouped by years or sector. Not all sectors have the same year info and not all years have the same sectors in them. The years and sector objects are used to dynamically create check boxes, for filtering by year or sector. I then combined them to filter from the check boxes...does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flat the result array and then filter duplicates out by using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with a closure.

```js
var array = [[{ id: 4, name: "charity5", sector: "Homeless", year: 2018, description: "lorem ipsum", address: "", Postleitzahl: "", bundesland: "", latitude: 51.9500019, longitude: 7.4836722, donations: 60000, image: "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city", logo: "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract" }, { id: 5, name: "charity6", sector: "Homeless", year: 2018, description: "lorem ipsum", address: "", Postleitzahl: "", bundesland: "", latitude: 50.9500019, longitude: 6.4836722, donations: 60000, image: "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city", logo: "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract" }], [{ id: 2, name: "charity3", sector: "Seniors", year: 2018, description: "lorem ipsum", address: "", Postleitzahl: "", bundesland: "", latitude: 51.5413, longitude: 9.9158, donations: 70000, image: "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/people", logo: "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract" }, { id: 4, name: "charity5", sector: "Homeless", year: 2018, description: "lorem ipsum", address: "", Postleitzahl: "", bundesland: "", latitude: 51.9500019, longitude: 7.4836722, donations: 60000, image: "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city", logo: "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract" }, { id: 5, name: "charity6", sector: "Homeless", year: 2018, description: "lorem ipsum", address: "", Postleitzahl: "", bundesland: "", latitude: 50.9500019, longitude: 6.4836722, donations: 60000, image: "https://lorempixel.com/321/200/city", logo: "https://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract" }]],
    result = array
        .reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a), [])
        .filter((s => o => !s.has(o.id) && s.add(o.id))(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Nina that worked perfectly, I can't quite follow what's happening in filter, I'll need to pick it apart to understand better. Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: it is the same like `var s = new Set;` and then with the callback of `(o => !s.has(o.id) && s.add(o.id))`, which check if `id` is in the set and if not, it adds it to the set.